# Django + pandas: Как передать пользователю сгенерированный excel документ?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pandas

На основании введенных на сайте пользователем данных, view должно генерировать excel-документ. Подскажите, как его правильно передать в браузер?

То, что делаю я - ничего не получается (или скачивается пустой документ):

```
excelData = data.to_excel
response = HttpResponse(excelData, content_type="application/vnd.ms-excel")
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=worksheet.xls'

return response
```

Comment: data.to_excel  —> data.to_excel(“ /path/to/worksheet.xls”)

Answer (score 0):

```
file_name = "file_name"
path_download = "path_download"
temp = file_name.split('/')
file_type = "file_type"


dict_type = {'.doc': 'application/msword',
             '.docx': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
             '.dot': 'application/msword',
             '.dotx': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template',
             '.docm': 'application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12',
             '.dotm': 'application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12',
             '.xls': 'application/vnd.ms-excel', '.xla': 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
             '.xlsx': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
             '.xltx': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template',
             '.xlsm': 'application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12',
             '.xltm': 'application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12',
             '.xlam': 'application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12',
             '.xlsb': 'application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12',
             '.ppt': 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
             '.pot': 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint', '.pps': 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
             '.ppa': 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
             '.pptx': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation',
             '.potx': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template',
             '.ppsx': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow',
             '.ppam': 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12',
             '.pptm': 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12',
             '.potm': 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12',
             '.ppsm': 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12',
             '.mdb': 'application/vnd.ms-access', '.pdf': 'application/pdf',
             }

for i in dict_type:
    if i == file_type:
        file_type = dict_type[i]
        break

if os.path.exists(path_download):
    with open(path_download, 'rb') as fl:
       response = HttpResponse(fl.read(), content_type=file_type, charset='utf-8')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={0}'.format(urlquote(file_name))
        response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(path_download)
        return response
raise Http404
```

Так как тебе нужен Excel, то `.xls': 'application/vnd.ms-excel'` это твой вариант.

UPD:

Моя html разметка

```
<form id="save" action="{% url 'knowledgebase:save_request' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>
        <span>
            Процесс *

        </span>
        {{ form.process_name }}
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>Кол-во операций в день *</span>
        {{ form.operation }}
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>Высвобождение минут за одну операцию *</span>
        {{ form.minutes }}
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>Эффект ПШЕ *</span>
        {{ form.effect }}
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>Перечень задействованных АС *</span>
        {{ form.per_as }}
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>E-mail *</span>
        {{ form.client_email }}
    </label>
<br>
    <label>
        <span>Описание заявки *</span>
        {{ form.description }}
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>Инфраструктурный эффект (минимизация рисковой зоны).</span>
        {{ form.another }}
    </label>

    <div>
        <input type="file" name="files" id="id_files">
        <label id="label_protokol" name="a" class="file" for="id_files">Вложить файл схемы оптимизируемого процесса</label>
    </div>

<br>
    <label style="width:25%;">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input style="color:black" type="submit" id="submit" value="Отправить заявку"/>
            <img class="text-center" src="{% static 'knowledgebase/image/curved-bars.svg' %}" id="img" style="display: none">
        </div>
    </label>

</form>
```

JS на том же шаблоне снизу

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#save').submit(function(){
            var spinner = $('#img');
            var data = new FormData($("#save").get(0));

            spinner.show();
            $('#submit').hide();
            console.log($(this).serialize());
            $.ajax({
                type:$(this).attr('method'),
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                data: data,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                statusCode: {
                    500: function() {
                        $("#error").show();
                        $("#error").text("Что-то пошло не так, пожалуйста, передайте введенные данные разработчику: Golovkin.M.I@omega.sbrf.ru");
                        spinner.hide();
                        $('#submit').show();
                    }
                },
                success: function(response){
                    window.location = response;
                }
            }).done(function(){spinner.hide();$('#submit').show();});
        return false;
        });

    });

</script>
```

Здесь я вместо кнопки отображаю крутящийся шарик.. имитация загрузки.. что-то в этом роде

Суть в чём ? Я обращаюсь к excel_request путем нажатия на кнопку на сайте
Я генерирую файл и сохраняю его, а в ответ на успешное окончание процесса я передаю путь до файла методом json.dumps(file_name)
По этому пути я иду и обращаюсь к другой views который уже и отдаёт файл

```
    views.py

    def excel_request(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            try:
                file_name = "request_" + str(AddRPA.objects.count() + 1) + '.xls'
            except:
                file_name = "new_request_" + str(1) + '.xls'
            path_download = file_path + 'docs/' + file_name
            data = AddRPA.objects.all()
            wb = xlwt.Workbook()
            ws = wb.add_sheet('Requests')

            style = xlwt.XFStyle()
            borders = xlwt.Borders()
            borders.left = xlwt.Borders.MEDIUM
            borders.right = xlwt.Borders.MEDIUM
            borders.bottom = xlwt.Borders.MEDIUM
            borders.top = xlwt.Borders.MEDIUM
            style.borders = borders

           columns = ['Процесс', 'Кол-во операций в день', 'Высвобождение минут за одну операцию', 'Эффект ПШЕ', 'Перечень задействованных АС',
                       'E-mail', 'Описание заявки', 'Инфраструктурный эффект']

            for n, i in enumerate(columns):
                ws.write(0, n, i, style)  # добавляем название столбцов

            for n, i in enumerate(data.iterator()):
                ws.write(n + 1, 0, i.process_name)
                ws.write(n + 1, 1, i.operation)
                ws.write(n + 1, 2, i.minutes)
                ws.write(n + 1, 3, i.effect)
                ws.write(n + 1, 4, i.auto_system)
                ws.write(n + 1, 5, i.e_mail)
                ws.write(n + 1, 6, i.description)
                ws.write(n + 1, 7, i.another)
            wb.save(path_download)

            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(file_name))
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/knowledgebase/home/add_request/')


    def filename_request(request, filename):
        my_type = 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
        path_download = file_path + 'docs/' + filename
        if os.path.exists(path_download):
            with open(path_download, 'rb') as fl:
                response = HttpResponse(fl.read(), content_type=my_type, charset='utf-8')
                response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={0}'.format(filename)
                response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(path_download)
                return response
        raise Http404

urls.py :
url(r'^' + app_name + '/home/add_request/excel_request/$', excel_request, name='excel_request'),
url(r'^' + app_name + '/home/add_request/excel_request_success/(?P<filename>.*)', filename_request, name='filename_request'),
```

Comment: Спасибо! Правильно ли я понимаю, что тут файл нужно при сборке сохранить на сервер и только потом отдать на клиент?

Comment: @Maxocoder Ваша функция выдаст почти тот же результат в его случае.

Comment: Подразумевается, что файл уже есть на сервере. В моём случае при сохранении файла в БД записывается путь до файла и берется этот путь и записывается в file_name и от туда я беру и путь до файла и наиманование файла и тип файла

Comment: Очень хотелось бы пример, где файл генерируется функцией и потом сохраняется. т.к. не уверен, что сервер сможет хранить много файлов

Comment: сейчас отредактирую свой ответ

Comment: немного объемный ответ.. но прочитай всё подробно и ты разберешься, если что, задавай вопросы